# Установка mysql в django, проблема?

Tags: mysql, python, django

Пытаюсь установить mysql в settigs.py , но мне выбивает ошибку:
P.S: не обращайте внимание на путь Openserver, он выключен(все через Python manage.py runserver)

```html
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper
 at 0x0309FA50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\m
ysql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autorel
oad.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\core\manageme
nt\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autorel
oad.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py"
, line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autorel
oad.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py",
 line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry
.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.p
y", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126,
in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\
models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\
base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\bas
e.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\bas
e.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\opt
ions.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length(
))
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.p
y", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
 line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
 line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126,
in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\m
ysql\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No mo
dule named 'MySQLdb'
```

Полный код ошибки, virtualenv запущен(я на виндовс)
Вот так пытаюсь подключить:

```js
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка `No module named 'MySQLdb'` означает, что у вас не установлен модуль доступа к mysql. Установите его командой `pip install MySQL-python`.

Comment: Пробовал и не раз.
В конце вылазит большая ошибка

Comment: Так покажите её.

Comment: Command "c:\openserver\domains\django_test\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setu
ptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Hehe\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-oyi2
d4d0\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file
__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\
Hehe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7pouu2lb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\openserver\domains\django_test
\include\site\python3.5\mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Hehe\A
ppData\Local\Temp\.символы

Comment: Только что наткнулся на вещь, что нужно создать папку mysqldb (с файлами конечно, не знаю какими), в virtualenv/lib/site-packages
Нету догадок?
Я конкретнее ничего не смог найти.

Comment: Попробуйте скачать отсюда http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python wheel подходящий к вашей операционной системе и версии Python, а после установить его командой `pip install имя_файла.whl` из папки, в которую скачали.

Comment: Установил. В общем, вроде-бы теперь все нормально, конечная ошибка пишет, про ошибку подключения к mysql-серверу.
Как настраивать теперь это все?

Comment: У вас mysql-сервер установлен и работает? С помощью `mysql -u root -p django` подключиться к базе можете?

Comment: У меня виндовс, не уверен, что я смогу выполнить команду mysql.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43928/discussion-between-sergey-gornostaev-and-deadmoras).